# Lock screen automatically in Cinnamon

Tags: lock-screen, cinnamon, screensaver, gnome-screensaver

How can I set computer to turn off my monitor and lock my screen after a minute in Cinnamon. In Unity I can just go to brightness and lock and set it but in Cinnamon I can't see that setting. If I go to power management, shortest time available is 5 minutes that is too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dconf-editor` (If not installed, install it with `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`) and change idle-delay in org.cinnamon.desktop.session to the desired time in seconds.